# Deleting and re instantiating an arrayed struct globally from within a function without knowing the size of the array at compile

Tags: c++, arduino

Full code: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/E22ZjbE7)

Full code with your comments enabled (Google Drive): [SerialGrapherV0.9](https://docs.google.com/document/d/193a8RCdreRLMRJGnt7iLq_qB8QVTOc0IVJ8S4D1M6eU/edit?usp=sharing)

Code-in-progress is near the bottom.

youTube example of graphing code running: [Grapher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOhJ6M41eao)

Background: My goal is to write a library to allow a caller Arduino to drive a callee Arduino via serial and print to a master-defined graph or graphs on an SSD1306 I2C display(no SPI version to test with). The graphing code is finished. Currently I can have 4 graphs that can update synchronously or asynchronously, there is no blanking and only writes the portions that need updating.

Both arduinos currently run the same sketch and determine their role via a pullup_input tied to ground, however in later versions the sketch will compile using if statements with a #defined boolean to greatly save on program space for the caller arduino.

So far:
The actual graphing is working and the graph updates whenever a graphAdd(graphNumber, newVal); is called. 
The xpos, ypos, xlength, and ylength, of each graph can be defined on the caller side as such:

```
#define masterGraphNum 4                  //Set this to the number of Graphs you want. 

graphStruct graph[masterGraphNum] = {             //Each set of brackets is an instance of a graph, one for each specified in graphNum, set the array number on the receiver to the max number of graphs you can use.
  //Graph 1                           //Usage: {LeftX, TopY, width, height}
  {0, 0, 31, 32},
  //Graph 2
  {32, 0, 31, 32},
  //Graph 3
  {64, 0, 31, 32},
  //Graph 4
  {96, 0, 31, 32},
};
```

Currently I am trying to use `delete[] (graph);` followed by `graphStruct *graph = new graphStruct[incomingGraphNum];` where incomingGraphNum is an int sent by the caller and received by the callee, this seems to work at first, however after a short time of graphing ~15 seconds the arduino crashes and restarts.

FLOW:

- Callee awaits connection indefinitely
- Caller sends ready byte
- Callee acks
- Caller sends number of graphs wanted
- NOT WORKING: Re-initializing graph
- Graph adds data via called function
- NYI: Sending graph number and new value over serial

My problem is now instantiating a globally accessible array of structs from within a function as I don't want to have to pre-code the number of graphs into the callee, as well as assign the size of the buffer array within the struct.

For the functions to work graph[] needs to be declared globally. I would like to globally declare graph[number of graphs] within a function during the callee setup, as I want to make this into a plug-and play diagnostic tool for my future projects.

Next Steps:
Setting up packets to send the graph data over. Not too hard, essentially sending two ints like (graph#, graphData)
Add graph "titling" (like "ACC" or "Light intensity")

Implemented:

- Graphing system
- Simple serial "call - response" system and acknowledgement system. (Just discovered the stream function included with the Arduino IDE, currently rewriting a few sections to use Serial.parseInt() instead of a modified serialEvent().
- Basic Error Handling
- Loops/Second counter

Comment: You can't `delete` an array...You seem to already have the answer: declare the global variable as a pointer: `graphStruct *graph  = nullptr;`. Then use `new` and `delete` to create/resize.

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately the arduino begins to run slower and slower and eventually crashes. I forgot to mention this. I'll update my post to include this information.

Comment: From what I understand, `new` and `delete` should be used sparingly on a microcontroller like the Arduino. You should initially make the array as large as you think you will need. Then, only re-alloc the array when a larger size is required. If a smaller size is needed, keep the array, just don't use it all.

Comment: The problem with this is that the user might want one big graph which would require a large buffer or many smaller graphs with many small buffers. The arduino doesn't have enough memory to allocate as many array members as I want with the largest possible buffer size. I only want to malloc once at the beginning during the initial serial setup then not touch it after.

Comment: There are only so many pixels in that little display. Why do you need to store so much data? Does the data arrive in a stream or all at once? (Also, I tried to look at the code but Google docs does not display it well. Pastebin is better as it has syntax highlighting and line numbers).

Comment: The display is 128 pixels wide, and it takes 2 bytes of buffer space for each y value in the array. Each graph instance takes 2 bytes each for the xpos, ypos, xwidth, yheight, readyBool, newVal. Lol, I asked this question over on the arduino forums: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=570277.0 and they told me they wouldn't help me cause I used pastebin. I'll go make a pastebin link for you and update my question.

Comment: The data arrives in a stream of 4 bytes, 2 for the int to tell the receiver which graph to add to and 2 for the incoming int.

Comment: It's a catch-22. On the one hand people prefer you put the code directly in your question. On the other hand some complain if you post too much code. Links to code are frowned upon because links can die. A [mcve] is prefered, but that's often hard to do with embedded code.

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas that may help.

The display is 128 pixels, so you need a buffer no larger than that. I suggest you make that a single, global buffer (instead of each struct having its own buffer). This will never need to be re-sized with `new/delete`, no matter how many graphs you have.

```
uint8_t global_graph_buffer[128];
```

Notice that I have changed it from `int` to `byte`. The height of the display is only 30 or 40 pixels (?) so there's no need to store any number bigger than that. Just scale the value down when it comes in on the port.

```
graph_buffer[x] = map(incoming_data, 0, max_input, 0, height_of_graph);
```

See the Arduino [`map()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/) function.

Next, do you really need the y_pos and height of the graphs? Do you plan on having more than 1 row of graphs? If not, get rid of those struct members. Also, you can get rid of the x_pos and width fields as well. These can be calculated based on the indexes.

```
struct graphStruct {
  uint8_t gx;  // Removed
  uint8_t gy;  // Removed
  uint8_t gw;  // Removed
  uint8_t gh;  // Removed
  int gVal;              // What is this for?
  //int graphBuffer[graphBufferSize]; This is gone
  uint8_t start_index;   // First index in the global array
  uint8_t end_index;     // Last index
  bool isReady;          // What is this for?
};
```

To calc x_pos and width:

```
x_pos = start_index
width = end_index - start_index
```

To handle incoming data, shift just the part of the buffer for the given graph and add the value:

```
int incoming_data = some_value_from_serial;
// Shift
for (byte i = graph[graphNumber].start_index+1; i < graph[graphNumber].end_index; i++) {
    global_graph_buffer[i] = global_graph_buffer[i-1]
 }
// Store
global_graph_buffer[i] = map(incoming_data, 0, graphMax, 0, 128);
```

Lastly, you need to consider: how many graphs can you realistically display at one time? Set a max, and create only that many structs at the start. If you use a global buffer, as I suggest, you can re-use a struct multiple times (without having to use `new/delete`). Just change the `start_index` and `end_index` fields.

Not sure if any of this helps, but maybe you can get some ideas from it.

Comment: The part about using map() is definitely helpful. The reason we need the x/y positions is because the code should be perfectly usable on the larger

Comment: displays running on the same oled driver, and I want the code to be portable to larger displays with a more powerful arduino-compatible arm processor. The bool isReady is a flag for a function at the end of the loop that checks if any graphs are ready to be updated instead of redrawing the screen every time. This brings it from ~8 loops per second to over 40. I have plans to hook up an arduino DUE or other arduino ide compatible microcontroller with a larger display.

Comment: I really like the idea of using one larger buffer and allocating chunks of that each individual graph needs. The stop and start locations could even be included in the buffer itself. The byte part will give me a lot more space to play with thank you. Assuming that you had a large enough display you could run a ton of slow-moving graphs, it's mostly just an issue of memory.

Comment: Yes, I think using a single buffer will bring the most improvement.